# Можно ли поместить декларацию переменной в условие?

Tags: c++, стандарт, объявление

Код:

```
player win = board.hasWon();
if (win != player::NONE) {
    cout << "WON PLAYER: " << win << endl;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Можно, но не нужно.

Comment: Как и почему..?

Comment: как - переносите объявление переменной внутрь круглых скобок if, перед условием. почему - потому что тогда получится каша из совмещенных объявлений и операций в одной строке. Ну и несколько разных переменных таким образом все равно не определить.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44177439/14775762

Comment: Это никоим образом не улучшит код (даже  количеством напечатанных символов)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan зато улучшит локальность кода

Comment: @Croessmah stands with Russia, мелочь(как капля в океане), тем более, что объект объявлен прямо перед циклом, и он и так является автоматическим.   Использование  printf вместо cout  больше улучшит код, чем эта мелочь, не говоря о всем остальном коде,  наверняка не написанным идеально.

Comment: Улучшит это код или нет — вопрос быть может спорный. Но добавление в язык возможности совместить инициализацию и `if` [обосновывается](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r0.html) именно желанием сделать код лучше.

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy, wowolo,  @Croessmah stands with Russia, Alex Glebe спасибо за ответ. Остальным за участие в вопросе ;)

Answer (score 1):

Можно, просто сделать копи-пасте :

```
if (player win = board.hasWon(); win != player::NONE) {
    cout << "WON PLAYER: " << win << endl;
    break;
}
```

*Другое дело: это сомнительный стиль, много действий в одной строке. И как подсказали в комментарии *user7860670* много разных типов уже нельзя.*

Comment: Много разных типов нельзя. Но можно сделать структуру из многих разных типов.

Comment: @Mikhailo , получилось в C++17 `if( struct { player win = board.hasWon(); int i = 1; long int l = i + 2;} S ; S.win != player::NONE )`. Но что-то длина команд в плюсах очень настораживает. Я больше люблю ассемблер.